# How to use m5 readfile and m5 execfile in gem5?

Tags: gem5

I expect `m5 readfile` will read a file from the host, and `m5 execfile` will execute a file from host, but the documentation is scarce and I couldn't get them to work.

Maybe the path is determined by `readfile=` in `m5out/config.ini`, but I don't know how to modify that setting when using `fs.py`; when I relaunch gem5 it overwrites that file.

I was able to use the related `m5 writefile` however with:

Guest:

```
echo mycontent > myfileguest
m5 writefile myfileguest myfilehost
```

Host:

```
cat m5out/myfilehost
```

Answer (score 1):

**`readfile`**

As of gem5 68af229490fc811aebddf68b3e2e09e63a5fa475 you can set the `readfile` path with:

```
fs.py --script=myfile
```

Unlike `writefile`, the path is relative to the current directory on the host, not `m5out`.

Then when you run `m5 readfile` in the guest, it outputs the contents of the file to stdout.

This does in the `fs.py` script:

```
if options.script is not None:
    test_sys.readfile = options.script
```

which seems to inherit from `class System`, which ends up serializing configurations to `config.ini` only for debugging purposes.

**execfile**

`execfile` is just a very light wrapper over `readfile`, that instead of writing the input file to stdout, writes it to `/tmp/execfile`, and runs the `exec` syscall on it from C.

However, as of 68af229490fc811aebddf68b3e2e09e63a5fa475, `m5` does not:

- open the file with `O_CREAT`
- set the appropriate executable permissions

so you must do on guest:

```
touch /tmp/execfile
chmod +x /tmp/execfile
m5 execfile
```

I'd just rather do this with `m5 readfile` and some scripting.

`m5 execfile` could be useful as an `init` program however, but I find argument passing to init programs too clumsy and unrealiable.